# How do i write Junit4 tests without Spring transactional test support?

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I would like to test transaction rollbacks in my application service. As a result i do not want to use spring's `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` with the `@Transactional` annotation as that wraps my test method in a transaction.

I know spring also offers `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests` for tests without transactions. However i need to have some transactions to save data into my database and also query data for assertions after running the service under test.

How can i write a Junit 4 spring transactional test without the default transaction test management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer to your question ;

```
@ContextConfiguration(value = "/applicationContext.xml")
public class JPASpringTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
 @PersistenceContext(unitName="jpadenemelocal")
 EntityManager entityManager;

 @Autowired
 protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

 @Test
 public void testInsertRolManyToMany() {
 TransactionStatus status =  transactionManager.getTransaction(null);
 // your code   

 transactionManager.commit(status);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spring docs should cover this in their [testing chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx)

What you might want is to configure your test without the default TransactionalTestExecutionListener like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        // execute test logic...
   }
}
```

Comment: Paul, would i then use the EntityManager to create transactions programatically when i need to use them?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite read your original question completely. So you actually need a Transaction in the test. In that case, creating it programatically would probably work, I think you need the JPATransactionManager for that. Then again, maybe you could do what you need to do declaratively by controlling the propagation behaviour. Maybe if you could provide an example test of what you need to do...